# how to tag clients with winsock

Tags: c++, c, windows, winsock

I have a simple server client winsock program running. And wanna know and add 2 things to it.

How do I tag/ID clients?

And be able to send ALL clients data after wards?

This is the connection loop I have at the moment. The "client_id[a]" is something I tried to tag/id the clients but probably incorrect.

```
for(;;)
{
 if(Connect = accept(Listen, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, &size))
  {
    std::cout<<"\nConnection was reached";    
    a = a +1;
    client_id[a] = accept(Listen, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, &size) ???
  }
}
```

Using C/C++ and windows.

Hopefully someone can help me solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "tagging" ? Do you simply want a list of clients ?

Comment: "Tagging" as in identifying/collecting/record them so I can send data to them later. Yea, a simple list of the clients would do I guess, as long as I can use that to send them data than. Whatever would work best for this.

Answer (score 0):

Each client connected to your server has already its own identifier SOCKET. do not use your custom identifier. Also use dynamic array -> std::vector or map in order to keep your clients.

Also you have double accept you will lose every second connection.

```
std::vector< SOCKET > clients;
...
for(;;)
{
 if(Connect = accept(Listen, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, &size))
  {
    std::cout<<"\nConnection was reached";    
    clients.push_back( Connect )
  }
}
```

In case of map you have something like

```
std::map< SOCKET, YouClientClass > clients;
...
for(;;)
{
 if(Connect = accept(Listen, (SOCKADDR*)&Server, &size))
  {
    std::cout<<"\nConnection was reached";    
    clients.insert( std::make_pair( Connect, YourClientClass(Connect))); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a simple example to get it working so I can test it?

Comment: Ok, so what exactly contains my clients? So that for example later I can do a simple for loop and send data to all clients?

Comment: Your clients will contain a list of unsigned int's - sockets, which are a system id's of connected client.

Comment: OK, and to send data to all clients "send_data ( &clients, message, BUFFER_SIZE );" in a for loop with "> clients" being the array containing them all? And how does it work when one disconnects?

Comment: In case if one is disconnected you have to remove it from your dynamic array - map. You should check if an client is disconnected on the receive loop.

Comment: Alright. And the "send_data" I wrote above still applies? Or do I have to do it in a different way?

Comment: in case of send you have to iterate your map-vector and send data to each client separately.But for better design use the solution with a map and implement send method in your Client class. so you have to iterate all of your clients and call sendData for each of them.

Comment: Would you mind adding it? I am a bit unsure about how to do it. I was gonna go for the vector example because it seemed easier. But are you saying the "map" sample is a better solution?

Comment: Yes it is better if you like to use the OO concept. By your problem analysis I am pretty sure that you have some kind of client as object with some properties which represent him, like name, maybe password, avatar and so on so you have to make an class with name Client and put all the data needed for your client in. But this is another question....

Comment: Oh no, clients won't have that actually. It doesn't matter if a client has a name/properties or not, they will all get the same data anyhow.